# Find pair of positive integers under a constraint that satisfy the inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory

I'm trying to solve this question. There's a constant $K$

And we've be given an inequality $X \cdot Y \leq K$.

Here $0 \leq X \leq A$ and $0 \leq Y \leq B$ and $K \geq 1$.

We need to find no of pairs of $X$ and $Y$ which satisfy this inequality

If there's a pair $(a,b)$ which satisfy and $(b,a)$ also. Then you need to count them both.

I can solve this using a brute force method. But i am thinking if there's some mathematical approach to this? So this can be done in constant time?

Comment: Well, for $X=1...  A$ Then $Y$ may be any $0.... \min (B, \lfloor \frac Kx\rfloor)$.... well, actually $\min(B, \lceil \frac Kx\rceil - 1)$.

Comment: It'd be $B + \sum_{j=1}^A(1 + \min(B,\lceil \frac Kj\rceil - 1)) = A + \sum_{j=1}^B(1 + \min(A,\lceil \frac Kj\rceil - 1))$

Comment: $x$ is $X$........

Comment: Thanks for replying but i already am using brute force to solve it. Just assume that $A$ and $B$ are very large. So i can't run any loops.I want to do it in constant time

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It, or questions very like it, have been coming up a lot over the last few days.

Comment: It's a question from Elements of Discreet Mathematics by C.L Liu page 386